# How do 'is' and '==' work for float values in Python?

Tags: python

I'm starting a basic online course of Python and I was wondering why when I use `is` when comparing two same float values `is` results as `False`.

I've been trying these combinations:

```py
# C1
x = 3
y = 3.0
x is y # False
```

```py
# C2
x = 3.0
y = 3
x is y # False
```

I know if I use `==` it appears true for the second combination because it is comparing values.

I was thinking it would appear for

```py
x = 3.0
y = 3.0
x is y # True
```

because it points to the same object, but instead, it appears as `False`.  Do you know why?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: _because it points to the same object_ No they do not.  `x` and `y` have the same _value_, but they are separate _objects_.  The `is` operator tests if two names point to the same _object_.

Comment: `is` has absolutely nothing to do with values - the only thing it tells you is whether the left and right operands are *the same object*.  An int and a float are certainly never going to be the same object.  Two floats with the same value may be the same object, or they may be different objects; there's no guarantee one way or the other, nor is there any particular reason for you to care.

Comment: Consider for a moment what it would require to do what you are thinking.  If would require Python to go through the list of all objects to figure out if `3.0` was already in an object somewhere.  Now, Python actually DOES that for small integers, but certainly not for floats.

Comment: There are two completely separate questions here, about `is` and about `==`. Both are well covered by existing separate Q&A.

Comment: @tdelaney *"The only defined singletons out there are None, True and False"* - And `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` (and I'm not sure there aren't even more...).

Comment: @tdelaney What makes you think that? I see it being a singleton [already in 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object) (didn't check further back).

Comment: @tdelaney Even in [Python 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref3.html#REF22319) it was already a singleton...